# Consider three infinitely long thin wires

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetostatics

> Each carrying current I in the same direction , are in $x$-$y$ plane. The central wire is along the $y$ axis, while the other along $x=+d$ and $-d$
>   Find the locus of points for which magnetic field is zero.

My approach: I had find the two lines in the x-y plane where magnetic field is zero easily,but my doubt is there will there more of such lines in plane other than $x$-$y$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, there are no such points R out of the x-y plane: for example, the sign of the x-component of the magnetic field created by each wire is the same for points with z>0 (you can consider the x-component of the cross product of a unit vector in direction y and the vector from the origin to the point R).

Comment: OK, I am able to visualize it now, but unable to understand how have you used cross product to prove the same, can you please explain that mathematically part again

Comment: @vikrant : The magnetic field of a current can be presented as a cross product. You can write out x- component of the cross product. If this hint is not enough... Well, I am not supposed to give a complete solution of homework.